# Explain the code?

Tags: c++, bind2nd

I came across this code. From the output I could infer that remainder array stores the remainder of numbers array when divided by 2. But the syntax is unfamiliar to me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main ( )
{

    int numbers[ ] = {1, 2, 3};

    int remainders[3];

    transform ( numbers, numbers + 3, remainders, bind2nd(modulus<int>( ), 2) );

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << (remainders[i] == 1 ? "odd" : "even") << "\n";
    }
    return 0;

}
```

What do transform and bind2nd do in this context? I read the documentation but it was not clear to me.

Comment: [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), no clue what :`bind2nd()` actually is.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ [`std::bind2nd`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind12).  Deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++17.

Comment: @Miles Cool, might explain a lot why the OP asks at all.

Comment: There fairly could be something like `bind2Tuple()` as a replacement then.

Comment: Yes, it's been replaced by `std::bind` and lambdas.

Comment: @MilesBudnek :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::bind2nd`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind12) is an old function for binding a value to the second parameter of a function.  It has been replaced by [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and lambdas.

`std::bind2nd` returns a callable object that takes one parameter and calls the wrapped callable with that parameter as its first parameter and the bound parameter as its second parameter:

```
int foo(int a, int b)
{
    std::cout << a << ' ' << b;
}

int main()
{
    auto bound = std::bind2nd(foo, 42);
    bound(10); // prints "10 42"
}
```

`std::bind2nd` (and its partner `std::bind1st`) were deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++17.  They were replaced in C++11 by the more flexible `std::bind` as well as lambda expressions:

```
int foo(int a, int b)
{
    std::cout << a << ' ' << b;
}

int main()
{
    auto bound = std::bind(foo, std::placeholders::_1, 42);
    bound(10); // prints "10 42", just like the std::bind2nd example above

    auto lambda = [](int a) { foo(a, 42); };
    lambda(10); // prints "10 42", same as the other examples
}
```

---

[`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) calls a callable on each element of a range and stores the result of the call into the output range.

```
int doubleIt(int i)
{
    return i * 2;
}

int main()
{
    int numbers[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int doubled[3];

    std::transform(numbers, numbers + 3, doubled, doubleIt);
    // doubled now contains { 2, 4, 6 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::bind2nd` is from C++98/03 (specifically, pre-lambdas).

`bin2nd(f, x)` assumes that `f` is a function (or at least something that can be invoked like a function) and `x` is a value that an be passed to that function as its second parameter. It creates something that acts like a function. When you call the function it creates, it's equivalent to calling `f(something, x)`, so it `binds` x to the second parameter of its input function.

Nowadays, you'd probably write this more like:

```
transform(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers), 
          remainders, 
          [](int x) { return x % 2; });
```

As for what transform does, it's pretty much like a loop, so this is roughly equivalent to:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    remainders[i] = numbers[i] % 2;
```

Overall, I think the original code is kind of half-baked. It looks to me like it was probably written when all this stuff was fairly new (or at least new to the author). If I were going to do this job overall, I'd probably "collapse" the operations together a bit:

```
std::transform(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers),
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"), 
            [](int i) { return std::to_string(i) + (i % 2 == 0 ? " is even" : " is odd"); });
```

The original doesn't seem to have any use for the `remainders` array except to hold an intermediate value before printing out the result, so it's probably better not to create/populate it at all.